# pythonstring value vs string in django orm

Tags: python-3.x, string, django-orm

[image]

this is what I want

[image]

I made the parameter by str value.
because I have to get parameters by list variable.

[image]

but when I use str parameter in filter, wrong result is comming.

[image]

whole source is here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first picture, you are providing a list of strings and in the second picture, you are providing string.

You can solve it by:

```
import json
fieldQueryString = json.loads(fieldQueryString)
```

this will convert this string into a list. So the output will change from

```
'["001", "002", "004", "005", "006"]'    # this is a string
```

to

```
["001", "002", "004", "005", "006"]     # this is a list
```

(notice the quotes before and after `[` and `]`).

Comment: perfect explanation. it works very well. thank you very much